# First order necessary conditions for nondifferentiable nonconvex minimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am interested in first order necessary conditions for the following minimization problem where the function $f$ is continuous, nondecreasing and concave, with $f(0)=0$, but not necessarily differentiable:

$\min \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(y_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}$

subject to:

$y_i = \sum_{j=i}^n x_j$

$0 \le x_i \le L$ for all $1 \le i \le n$.

Note that if we know that the minimum value of the objective is $F$, then we could equivalently write the objective as:

$\min \sum_{i=1}^n f(y_i) - F \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$

if that is helpful.

The problem here is that the objective is not differentiable or convex but it seems that the obvious subgradient version of the KKT conditions should hold: do they?

Comment: "it seems that the obvious subgradient version of the KKT conditions should hold" What makes you say this?